# Mostrar de un determinado tiempo window form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas estoy realizando en **window form** un modulo donde tengo 4 **label** y un botón.
Al principio esos label van estar oculto y cuando  presione el botón el primer **label** aparezca de un determinado tiempo una vez que aparezca el segundo **label** también aparezca de un determinado tiempo y sucesivamente.
Yo lo realize en webform.aspnet lo realize con javascript.
Pero en window form no usan javascript.
Quisiera que me pudieran ayudar . adjunto la imagen para que me entiendan mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En fin kieres que vayan apareciendo progresivamente????

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas si hermano

Comment: Ok ahora te pongo un ejemplo

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas mil gracias hermano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mira cree una funcion llamada setInterval para pasarle el tiempo que quiero que demore en que aparezcan cada label y un callback con lo que quiero que se ejecute en ese tiempo.

```
private void SetInterval(int interval, EventHandler callback)
{
    //Creo el temporizador
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //Le establezco el intervalo en el que va a repetir la operación
    timer.Interval = interval;
    //Asigno que se ejecutara al llegar el tiempo estimado
    timer.Tick += (obj, ev) =>
    {
        //En este caso ejecuto el callback que paso como parametro
        callback(obj, ev);
    };
    //Inicializo el temporizador
    timer.Start();
}
```

Ahora en el evento onClick del button llamo a setInterval y voy comprobando si estan visibles los botones y los voy mostrando progresivamente, tengo dos maneras una que es dificil de mantener si vas a incrementar los labels a mostrar y otra que es mas óptima, te voy a poner las dos y tu decides cual emplear

**FACIL:**

```
SetInterval(1000, (obj, ev) =>
{
    if (!label1.Visible)
    {
        label1.Show();
    }
    else if (!label2.Visible)
    {
        label2.Show();
    }
    else if (!label3.Visible)
    {
        label3.Show();
    }
    else if(!label4.Visible)
    {
        label4.Show();
    }       
});
```

**MAS OPTIMA:**

```
//Aqui guardo todos los labels que quiero mostrar progresivamente ordenados por el orden de aparición
Control[] labels = new Control[] { label1, label2, label3, label4 };
//Guardo la posición en la que debo comenzar en el Tag del botón
button1.Tag = 0;
//Llamo a la función creada
SetInterval(1000, (obj, ev) =>
{       
    //Obtengo la posición actual sobre la cual voy a trabajar
    int pos = Convert.ToInt32(button1.Tag);
    //Si no estoy fuera de los limites del arreglo de labels y el label esta oculto...
    if (pos < labels.Length && !labels[pos].Visible)
    {
        //Muestro el label correspondiente por el orden
        labels[pos++].Show();
        //Actualizo la posición en la que se quedo del arreglo de labels
        button1.Tag = pos;
    } 
});
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Ramos Días de Villegas eres genial si resulto yo solo pensaba que se podia hacer en web con javascript pero eres genial si se pudo te recontra agradesco Maestro.

Comment: Jajjaja no tanto como para maestro dale saludos

Comment: sabes mvc c#  hermano ?

Comment: +1 por el detalle en las explicaciones!

Comment: Se agradece cualquier punto extra ;P

Comment: @dariel ramos estas ahí ?

Comment: dime @Pierro que necesitas???

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas  cuando presiono otro boton y presiono para que se genere cierto tiempo ya no se muestra el tiempo y me vota defrente

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas es decir en mi primea vez sale bacan pero ahora le he agregad otro boton 
que cuando presiono y vuelvo a presionar el boton para que haga aparesca cierto segundos ya no sale sale directo

Comment: Explicate mejor que funcion tiene este segundo boton. O mejor has otra pregunta aki en stack y me avisas. saludos

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas hermano aqui esta espero que me entiendas porfis te lo suplico: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178533/mostrar-determinado-tiempo-window-form

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas porfis.