# Mostrar determinado tiempo window form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas estoy realizando en window form un mini sistema que cuando son 2 botones

1: primer boton que se llama sorteo es para que aparesca de un determinado tiempo y aparecen mis 8 numeros label
2: boton regenerar  solo es blanquear es decir que se pongan nuevamente visible

pero mi problema es que cuando primero pongo el boton sorteo se muestra correctamente de un determinado tiempo ,

ahora cuando termina y pongo el segundo boton y luego presiono el primer boton ahora me muestra de golpe.

**esta es la parte de la vista del window form**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**este es mi codigo del primer boton:**

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 SetInterval(1000, (obj, ev) =>
            {
                if (!lbln1.Visible)
                {
                    lbln1.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbln2.Visible)
                {
                    lbln2.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbln3.Visible)
                {
                    lbln3.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbln4.Visible)
                {
                    lbln4.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbln5.Visible)
                {
                    lbln5.Show();
                }

                else if (!lbln6.Visible)
                {
                    lbln6.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbln7.Visible)
                {
                    lbln7.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbln8.Visible)
                {
                    lbln8.Show();
                }
                else if (!label1.Visible)
                {
                    label1.Show();
                }

                else if (!lblcliente.Visible)
                {
                    lblcliente.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbloficina.Visible)
                {
                    lbloficina.Show();
                }
                else if (!lblfelicitaciones.Visible)
                {
                    lblfelicitaciones.Show();
                }
                else if (!lbldireccion.Visible)
                {
                    lbldireccion.Show();
                }

            });
}
```

**Segundo Botón:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Desea Sortear Nuevamente?", "Aviso del sistema",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Question);
             if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
             {lbln1.Text = "";
                 lbln2.Text = "";
                 lbln3.Text = "";
                 lbln4.Text = "";
                 lbln5.Text = "";
                 lbln6.Text = "";
                 lbln7.Text = "";
                 lbln8.Text = "";
                 lblcliente.Text = "";
                 lblfelicitaciones.Text = "";
                 lblnoesganador.Text = "";
                 lbloficina.Text = "";
                 lbldireccion.Text = "";
                 label1.Text = "";

                 MessageBox.Show("Se regenero el sorteo correctamente", "Aviso del Sistema");
                 button2.Enabled = false;

             }
        }
```

**esto es mi void SetInterval**

```
private void SetInterval(int interval, EventHandler callback)
        {
            //Creo el temporizador

            Timer timer = new Timer();


            //Le establezco el intervalo en el que va a repetir la operación
            //timer.Interval = interval;

            timer.Interval = interval;

            //Asigno que se ejecutara al llegar el tiempo estimado
            timer.Tick += (obj, ev) =>
            {
                //En este caso ejecuto el callback que paso como parametro
                callback(obj, ev);

            };
            //Inicializo el temporizador
            timer.Start();

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como que web? es web o escritorio?

Comment: Porque hay tanto lio de callbacks, timers y esas cosas.. esto es web o winforms??? es mucho mas simple si es winforms...

Comment: @gbianchi es window form

Comment: pero ahi arriba dice, esta es la parte de la web? y porque no tenes los timers directamente en el form y los eventos ya listos?

Comment: @gbianchi tenias razon escribi rapido que ni me di cuenta.
me guie de esta respuesta.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172553/mostrar-de-un-determinado-tiempo-window-form-c

Comment: si pero eso es web.. esto es mucho mas simple y no se necesita semejante complejidad.... Dame un rato y te armo un ejemplo casi sin codigo

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias no domino mucho window form.

Comment: Hermano, ten la amabilidad de editar la pregunta, cambiando esa imagen por código. Gracias :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas complicando algo, que en `winforms` se hace con los propios controles del formulario.

Agrega en el formulario 6 labels, 2 botones y un control TIMER.

deja los nombres por defecto, salvo el del `timer`, cámbialo por `tmrMostrar` y pon la propiedad `interval` en 1000.

Vas a tener que conectar los eventos que describo mas abajo a sus controles. Hay un evento para el primer boton, otro para el segundo y un evento tick para el timer.

El codigo simplificado con explicaciones en los comentarios es:

```
//Lista de los labels a ir mostrando
private List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
//Siguiente label a mostrar
private int LabelAMostrar = 1;
//El valor del ultimo label, o la cantidad
private int MaximoLabel = 6;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Armo un array de controles, se puede recorrer el form, pero asi es mas rapido
    labels.Add(label1);
    labels.Add(label2);
    labels.Add(label3);
    labels.Add(label4);
    labels.Add(label5);
    labels.Add(label6);
    cambiarEstadoLabels(false);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Empezar el timer
    tmrMostrar.Start();
    //apagar el boton
    button1.Visible = false;
}

private void cambiarEstadoLabels(bool estado)
{
    foreach (Label l in labels)
    {
        l.Visible = estado;
    }
}

private void tmrMostrar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Esto se podria hacer mucho mejor con linq
    foreach (Label l in labels)
    {
        if (l.Name == $"label{LabelAMostrar}")
        {
            l.Visible = true;
            LabelAMostrar += 1;
            if (LabelAMostrar > MaximoLabel)
            {
                //apago el timer
                tmrMostrar.Stop();
                //Muestro el boton de reseteo
                button2.Visible = true;
            }
            //si llegue aca, es que ya encontre el label a mostrar
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cambiarEstadoLabels(false);
    button2.Visible = false;
    button1.Visible = true;
    LabelAMostrar = 1;
}
```

Este código va a mostrar un `label` por segundo, hasta llegar al ultimo.

Comment: disculpa maestro me sale un error en tick

Comment: adjunte en m pregunta la imagen

Comment: ah.. saca la imagen... para que version estas compilando?? el problema es ese.. estoy usando sintaxis de 6 en adelante.. cambialo por "label"+LabelAMostrar.ToString()